# Focus on certain element within a overlay using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an overlay that pops up when you add an item to the cart and was wondering if anyone knows how i can focus on a certain area within the overlay... like darker rest of the overlay and the certain area be more visible.

Quick mockup:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="cm-notification-content cm-notification-content-extended notification-content-extended  cm-auto-hide" data-ca-notification-key="3b71ec814b1cb78f78b7b6602c6258a6" style="top: 143.5px;"><h1>Congrats. You've just added to Cart ...<span class="cm-notification-close close"></span></h1><div class="notification-body-extended"><div class="ty-product-notification__body cm-notification-max-height" style="max-height: 367px;">

            <div class="ty-product-notification__item clearfix">
                <img class="ty-pict  ty-product-notification__image  " src="http://aus2015.ambientlounge.com/images/thumbnails/100/100/detailed/2/wildberry.jpg?t=1440337739" alt="" title="">
                <div class="ty-product-notification__content clearfix butterfly-sofa-bean-bags">
                    <a href="http://aus2015.ambientlounge.com/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/acoustic-sofa-bean-bags/wildberry-deluxe.html" class="ty-product-notification__product-name">Wildberry Deluxe</a>
                                            <div class="ty-product-notification__price">
                                                            <span class="none">1</span>&nbsp;x&nbsp;<span class="none">$</span><span id="sec_price_2343099257" class="none">269.00</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                        </div>
            </div>


<form action="search_postcode.php" method="post" class="postcode_locator_form" name="postcode_locator_form">
    <div class="ty-control-group">
        <label for="postcode_locator_search" class="ty-control-group__title">Check we can send you filling (metro only)</label>
        <div class="ty-input-append ty-m-none">
            <input type="text" size="20" class="ty-input-text" id="postcode_locator_search" name="postcode_locator_search" value="" placeholder="Enter postcode">
            <button title="Search" class="ty-btn-go" type="submit">Go!</button>
<input type="hidden" name="dispatch" value="postcode_locator.search">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

<div class="filling-status filling-success" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Add filling to your bean bag</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>Searched postcode: <span class="searched-postcode"></span></p>
    <p class="beans-msg alert alert-success">Congratulations! we are able to deliver beans to your postcode! To add filling to your bean bag just <a href="http://aus2015.ambientlounge.com/index.php?dispatch=checkout.add_bean_bag_filling&amp;product_id=727">click here</a></p>
</div>
<div class="filling-status filling-failure" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Add filling to your bean bag</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>Searched postcode: <span class="searched-postcode"></span></p>
    <p class="beans-msg alert alert-error">Unfortunately we cannot delivery filling to your postcode, your item has already been added to your Cart but you will receive the cover only.</p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

    $(".filling-status").hide();
    $(".postcode_locator_form .ty-btn-go").click(function() {
        // getting the value that user typed
        var searchString    = $("#postcode_locator_search").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data            = 'postcode_locator_search='+ searchString;

        // if searchString is not empty
        if(searchString) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_postcode.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(data) { // this happens before actual call
                    $(".searched-postcode").html(searchString);
                },
                success: function(data){ // this happens after we get results
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == '0'){
                        $(".filling-status.filling-failure").hide();
                        $(".filling-status.filling-success").show();
                    } else if(data == '1'){
                        $(".filling-status.filling-success").hide();
                        $(".filling-status.filling-failure").show();
                    }
                }
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr class="ty-product-notification__divider">

    <div class="ty-product-notification__total-info clearfix">
        <div class="ty-product-notification__amount ty-float-left"> You now have 35 items in your cart</div>
        <div class="ty-product-notification__subtotal ty-float-right">
            Cart subtotal $<span>7,337.85</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><div class="ty-product-notification__buttons clearfix">    <div class="ty-float-left">



    <a href="http://aus2015.ambientlounge.com/index.php?dispatch=checkout.cart" class="ty-btn ty-btn__secondary ">View my Cart</a>

    </div>
            <div class="ty-float-right">



    <a href="http://aus2015.ambientlounge.com/index.php?dispatch=checkout.checkout" class="ty-btn ty-btn__primary ">Pay Now</a>

        </div>
    </div></div></div>
```

Comment: where is HTML and CSS for your elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you show the overlay, just execute this one:

```
$("#postcode_locator_search").focus();
```

**Tried a Mockup**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function () {
    $("body").prepend('<div class="mask"></div>');
    $("li:nth-child(2)").addClass("check").find("input").focus();
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
li {margin: 0 0 10px;}
.mask {position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
li.check {position: relative; z-index: 2; background-color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Input 1</strong>
        <input type="text" name="" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Input 2</strong>
        <input type="text" name="" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Input 3</strong>
        <input type="text" name="" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Input 4</strong>
        <input type="text" name="" />
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <strong>Input 5</strong>
        <input type="text" name="" />
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="btn">
```

Comment: I dont want to just focus, want to highlight it as well which making the rest of the overlay darker like in the mockup i done.

Comment: @James, are there more areas for highlighting, or just one?

Comment: @James So does it mean that you haven't implemented the overlay functionality?

Comment: @James, you will have to add small overlay to popup on your page, too (tested on your site), that's it, or to remove part of popup you don't need...

Comment: It already has the overlay popup, just want to focus on that one area, i need to keep the whole overlay and if success from a poscode search ill remove the highlight.

Comment: @James Tried something. Have a look.

Comment: Having a look now, ill integrate. Give me 5 mins mate and thanks

Comment: Perfect, need to tweak it up but its coming together! thanks for your help mate.